# Is it possible to add new packages and run docker non-dev file?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-superset

I have been working on Superset (cloned the code from superset github).Created new file under the folder superset/superset/ named db_access.py.
I have imported this file in the existing app.py file .Now have the following imports in the newly created file,

**db_access.py**

```
import boto3
import sys
import hvac
import pymysql
import psycopg2
import os
import io
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import traceback
from timestream_reader import Timestream_reader
import json
from pathlib import Path
from zenpy import Zenpy
```

app.py

```
import logging
import os
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,jsonify
from superset.initialization import SupersetAppInitializer
import sys
from superset.db_access import Db_access
```

I have included the hvac in requirements.txt and when I am composing docker dev file, it works with out any issue.
But when I try to compose the non-dev docker file with the above code, it shows error like hvac module not found (I tried pip install hvac and included that in requirements file too).Is there any other places that I need to customize based on new imports for non-dev?

**docker-compose-non-dev.yml**

```
x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - db
  - redis
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - superset_home:/app/superset_home
  - ./superset:/app/superset
  - ./superset-frontend:/app/superset-frontend
  
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: superset_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  db:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
    user: "root"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-init:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_init
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-init.sh"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

  superset-worker:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "celery inspect ping -A superset.tasks.celery_app:app -d celery@$$HOSTNAME"]

  superset-worker-beat:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker_beat
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

volumes:
  superset_home:
    external: false
  db_home:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

**docker-compose.yml (dev)**

```
x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}
x-superset-user: &superset-user root
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - db
  - redis
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - ./superset:/app/superset
  - ./superset-frontend:/app/superset-frontend
  - superset_home:/app/superset_home
  - ./tests:/app/tests

version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: superset_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  db:
    env_file: docker/.env
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset:
    env_file: docker/.env
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    user: *superset-user
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    environment:
      CYPRESS_CONFIG: "${CYPRESS_CONFIG}"

  superset-websocket:
    container_name: superset_websocket
    build: ./superset-websocket
    image: superset-websocket
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - redis
    # Mount everything in superset-websocket into container and
    # then exclude node_modules and dist with bogus volume mount.
    # This is necessary because host and container need to have
    # their own, separate versions of these files. .dockerignore
    # does not seem to work when starting the service through
    # docker-compose.
    #
    # For example, node_modules may contain libs with native bindings.
    # Those bindings need to be compiled for each OS and the container
    # OS is not necessarily the same as host OS.
    volumes:
      - ./superset-websocket:/home/superset-websocket
      - /home/superset-websocket/node_modules
      - /home/superset-websocket/dist
    environment:
      - PORT=8080
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_SSL=false

  superset-init:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_init
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-init.sh"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: *superset-user
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    environment:
      CYPRESS_CONFIG: "${CYPRESS_CONFIG}"
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

  superset-node:
    image: node:16
    container_name: superset_node
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-frontend.sh"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-worker:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: *superset-user
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "celery inspect ping -A superset.tasks.celery_app:app -d celery@$$HOSTNAME"]
    # Bump memory limit if processing selenium / thumbnails on superset-worker
    # mem_limit: 2038m
    # mem_reservation: 128M

  superset-worker-beat:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker_beat
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: *superset-user
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

  superset-tests-worker:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_tests_worker
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: localhost
      DATABASE_DB: test
      REDIS_CELERY_DB: 2
      REDIS_RESULTS_DB: 3
      REDIS_HOST: localhost
    network_mode: host
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: *superset-user
    volumes: *superset-volumes
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "celery inspect ping -A superset.tasks.celery_app:app -d celery@$$HOSTNAME"]

volumes:
  superset_home:
    external: false
  db_home:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

Comment: You need to include your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and any commands you're running especially if you're tagging this with `docker` and `docker-compose`.

Comment: @cam , As per your comments I have included my docker files

Comment: Can you try with [this]( https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/docker-add-drivers) procedure